# How to extract specific string in a bracket within an email subject with multiple parentheses/brackets?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, gmail

I am trying to extract specific string within a bracket within an email subject.

Here is the current code:

```
var vendorNo = msg[j].getSubject().split('Vendor No:')[1].replace(/[A-Za-z-0-9]+$/,'').slice(1, -1); //vendor number from email subject
```

The code I am currently using has no problem with extracting the vendor number from email subjects with single bracket, but the problem occurs when the subject has multiple brackets.

**For example:**

Email Subject: Supplier A (Vendor No.: 12345(EDC1))

Output: 123456(EDC1)

*Desired output: 123456*

OR

Email Subject: Supplier B (Vendor No.: 987654) [ref:xxxxxxxxx]

Output: 987654) [ref:xxxxxxxxx

*Desired output: 987654*

---

The current code is not quite correct because it extracts all the other strings after the `Vendor No:` and only removes the last character after the extraction. The vendor number may also varies, it can go from 5-8 characters and can be mix of numbers and alphabets (eg. 123CFT or 1234567).

I've tried `.slice(1, 7)` but it's not flexible for strings with more or less than the number of characters.

So is there a solution so the code would only extract only the one part of the string within the specific bracket which is the vendor number?

Comment: use `/\d+/` simply

Comment: @decpk The vendor number also may not necessarily only contains digits, can be mixed with alphabets. Sorry I've edit it in my post.

Comment: Then you can use `/\d[^\W]+/` or simply `/\d\w+/` or `(?=\d)\w+`

Comment: @Spectric yes, thank you for pointing that out. I didn't notice the typo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can split to get the part after `":"` and use [`String.search`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/search) to get the index of the first character that is a special character:

```js
function getVendorNo(s) {
  return  a = s.split(":")[1].trim(), a.substring(0, a.search(new RegExp("[^a-zA-Z0-9]")));
}

console.log(getVendorNo("Supplier A (Vendor No.: 12345(EDC1))"));
console.log(getVendorNo("Supplier B (Vendor No.: 987654) [ref:xxxxxxxxx]"));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use any one of the regex

```
/\d[^\W]+/
```

or

```
/\d\w+/
```

or

```
/(?=\d)\w+/
```

```js
const str = "Email Subject: Supplier A (Vendor No.: 12345(EDC1))";

const result1 = str.match(/\d[^\W]+/);
const result2 = str.match(/\d\w+/);
const result3 = str.match(/(?=\d)\w+/);

console.log(result1)
console.log(result2)
console.log(result3)
```